# Does ethnic background affect language learning strategies?

Tags: learning-methods, reference-request

Drawing inspiration from the question [Does ethnic background affect the speed of foreign language acquisition?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2568/800), I would like to ask something more specific: **Is there any research on how ethnic background affects language learning strategies?**

Wikipedia defines [language learning strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Language_learning_strategies&oldid=759177637) as

> the processes and actions that are consciously deployed by language learners to help them to learn or use a language more effectively.

Language learning strategies have been [classified in various ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Language_learning_strategies&oldid=759177637#Classification_of_language_learning_strategies), but that should not matter for this question, unless it turns out that there has been a massive amount of research on each type of strategy.